# dump($file) showing as "C:\xampp\tmp\php17A8.tmp" with error: Call to a member function guessExtension() on string

Tags: symfony, symfony4

First of all it is giving error :
Call to a member function guessExtension() on string

and when i do dump($file)
It Displays:
"C:\xampp\tmp\php17A8.tmp"

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $imageEn = new Image();

     $form = $this->createForm(ImageUploadType::class, $imageEn);

     $form->handleRequest($request);

     if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){

        /** @var Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile $file */

        $file = $imageEn->getImage();
        dump($file);

        $fileName = md5(uniqid()).'.'.$file->guessExtension();

        $file->move($this->getParameter('image_directory'), $fileName);

        $imageEn->setImage($fileName);
        $em->persist($imageEn);
        $em->flush();

        $this->addFlash('notice', 'Post Submitted Successfully!!!');

        return $this->redirectToRoute('image_upload');

     }

     return $this->render('image/image.html.twig', array(

        'imageform' => $form->createView()
     ));
}
```

Form:

```
  {
    $builder
        ->add('title', TextType::class)
        ->add('description', TextType::class)
        ->add('image', FileType::class, array('label'=>'Upload Image'))
        ->add('submit', SubmitType::class)
    ;
}
```

I have done almost everything but still i'm getting error.. I did same as in doc but still the same...

Actually I followed a tutorial where he made this class manually but I used Command to create class, I tallied all his code with mine and it was correct.

```
  <?php

   namespace App\Entity;

   use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
   use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

   /**
   * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ImageRepository")
   */
   class Image
  {
  /**
  * @ORM\Id()
  * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
  * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
  */
  private $id;

  /**
  * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
  */
  private $title;

  /**
  * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
  */
  private $description;

  /**
  * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
  * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please upload image")
  * @Assert\File(mimeTypes={"image/jpeg"})
  */
  private $image;

  public function getId()
  {
   return $this->id;
  }

  public function getTitle(): ?string
  {
  return $this->title; 
  }

  public function setTitle(string $title): self
  {
   $this->title = $title;

   return $this;
   }

   public function getDescription(): ?string
   {
   return $this->description;
   }

   public function setDescription(string $description): self
   {
   $this->description = $description;

   return $this;
   }

   public function getImage(): ?string
  {
  return $this->image;
  }

  public function setImage(string $image): self
  {
  $this->image = $image;

  return $this;
  }

}
```

Comment: Did you clear the symfony cache? Has the `image` field inside your form been a 'text' at any time?

Comment: I have cleared the cache, and the image is in file type

Comment: What does `gettype($file)` (and/or `get_class($file)` in case it's an object) return? Can you add the relevant parts of your entity to the question?

Comment: @ccKep, Please check the Entity...

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the types from your setter and getter method in your entity.

```
public function getImage()
{
    return $this->image;
}

public function setImage($image): self
{
    $this->image = $image;

    return $this;
}
```

If you add a type to these two methods, the __toString method from SplFileInfo will be called, because UploadedFile extends File and File extends SplFileInfo.

Comment: $file = $imageEn->getImage(); This part made the issue... Actually it should be $file = $form>get('image');